# Export question to epub or some other open ebook formats

Tags: feature-request, export

I would like to store and read on my ebook reader a lot of this incredible treasure found on stack Overflow.

I'm talking about popular questions like this one
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640/great-programming-quotes
that has many pages and hidden comments.

Print to PDF is not helpful because:

1. PDF is not an Ebook format
2. Questions could have hidden comments
3. Question could have pagination

Will it ever be possible?

Comment: First and foremost, nothing hinders you to work on this yourself :) http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/

Comment: The data is available.  It's possible for you to download it in a big batch and do whatever you like with it.

Answer (score 2):

Brilliant question!
[StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com) solves part of your problem giving you a printer-friendly view of a question with all the comments and without pagination; you can't export this in ebub, but believe me, printed on PDF is not bad at all with that layout. (I read many articles in PDF on my Ebook reader)

<sub>..and remember that it is not stackOverflow but Stack Overflow.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

A single question?  Use a Print to PDF writer.

I think what you really want is a way to export a selected set of questions (say, for a particular tag or tags).  To do that, you would have to walk the search results in the web site and export each page, or sift through the data dump and print each one to your desired ebook format using a report template.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Actually PDF is not a great ebook format, and yes, i would like to export just one question without the hassle to export one page at a time.

Comment: Well, which ebook format did you have in mind?  The vast majority of ebooks I have read all come in PDF format.  Some are in Winhelp, but that blows chunks.  There are other, far less common formats such as Mobipocket, or even Microsoft Reader, but their advantages would have to far outweigh the ubiquity of PDF.

Comment: PDF is not a great ebook format because is print oriented and not display oriented as many other ebook format like.See this list http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_e-book_formats

Comment: I wouldn't touch any of those formats with a ten foot pole.  The only ones that are common enough to be considered non-proprietary are plain text, HTML, and PDF.

Comment: EPUB is extremely popular.

Answer (score 1):

[@Greg Hewgill](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill) has done it for the: [top 20 tags in ebook format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74399/stack-overflow-top-20-tags-in-ebook-format) in .mobi for the kindle.